# How do I keep browser's leave page warning from showing using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have a web page with a form.  The user can make data changes on the form.  For instance, they can put data in a field and select a checkbox. There is a case where a user puts data in a field and then clears it (same could happen for checkbox) and when the user navigates away from the page after clearing all data, they still get a warning from the browser (in my case Chrome or Safari) that asking them if they want to leave and lose their changes.

How do I clear the browser's changed status so an error does not occur, when the user has cleared any entered data?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. This is a built-in security feature of the browser so that users are aware that they are leaving a page.

Comment: This isn't done automatically by the browser, it's done by the JavaScript for the application by adding a `beforeunload` event handler. How it decides whether the warning needs to be displayed is up to each application.